# Calling jQuery Plugin with EmberJS Creates Race Condition

Tags: jquery, dom, ember.js, datatables

I'm using the [jQuery DataTables plugin](http://datatables.net/) to render data in Ember.  I'm running into classic race condition issues and some part of my understanding of Ember and the Ember run-loop must be incomplete.  Here's what's happening.

- I output a table of data in my Template, using `<table>...<tbody>{{#each user in model}}...`
- In my View, I call the DataTables library in the `didInsertElement` method, and wrap it in `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function() { $('#myTable').DataTable(); })`
- The first time I access this page  code, I get the following error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.`
- If I access it again, it works fine.

I have looked at similar StackOverflow posts on this:

- [Ember.js - "Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM" caused by template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495659/ember-js-cannot-perform-operations-on-a-metamorph-that-is-not-in-the-dom-cau)
- [ember js with datatables plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218090/ember-js-with-datatables-plugin)

But these fixes don't seem to work.  I suspect that DataTables is trying to update the DOM *before* Ember has finished rendering it, but then why doesn't my called `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', ...)` address that?

Strangely, I can get it work by doing the following:

**Old (Race Condition) Code in View:**

```
 didInsertElement: function() {
   Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function() {
       $('#orgUsers').DataTable();
   });
 }
```

**New Working Code in View:**

```
 didInsertElement: function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('#orgUsers').DataTable();
   }, 0);
 }
```

Note that I have specified a javascript `setTimeout` delay of 0 seconds!  But this works every time.

Can someone help me understand (1) why does wrapping this in `setTimeout()` solve all my problems, (2) what is the "Ember Way" to handle this?  Thanks!

Comment: Data tables is meant for a static table, and not suitable for Ember/Handlebars.  The moment the data changes and Ember attempts to manipulate the view you will run in to trouble.

Comment: kingpin2k makes a good point- I'm not familiar with `DataTable`, but it makes sense.  I have found that Ember is powerful enough to let me do lots of things I used to use libraries for...  I roll my own tables, personally.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to come around to that way of thinking. It seems crazy that tables with filter/sort/pagination aren't available out of the box in Ember, but it's also not too hard to roll your own. Thx for the all the input, guys.

Comment: @JoshPadnick: I'm literally in the exact same situation. Down to the T. What did you end up doing? I'm 2 hours in searching for a solution, but can't find anything relevant online except this SO question. Thanks!

Comment: See follow-up at http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/integrating-datatables-into-a-simple-emberjs-application/6109/2

Comment: @Josh Padnick, I am also having troubles in integrating Ember Model data with Jquery datatable. Could you please share your code as an example reference? Because, there is very less info available over internet to accomplish the task. It would be great if you can share your code over http://jsbin.com

Comment: @Josh Padnick, I will give +1 if you share the code.

Comment: @Ashok.N See http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/pagination-sorting-filtering-for-a-beginner/6097/4 for some guidelines on how I did it.  Unfortunately, I don't have the time to package up the code and clean out our app-specific items.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect this to work:

```
Ember.run.next(this, function() {
    Ember.$('#orgUsers').DataTable();
});
```

This is preferable to your `setTimeout` code.  Ember will schedule your function for the next run loop.  `didInsertElement` is called from a task in the `render` queue.  Your call to `scheduleOnce` goes into the `afterRender` queue, which is "downstream" from the `render` queue, but in the same loop iteration.

Using `run.next` will schedule the task in a new run loop, so there won't be lifecycle issues in the current loop.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and I did not realize there were multiple loop runs!  Unfortunately, this didn't work. I receive the same error: `Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.` Also of interest, with `Ember.run.next` there is now a slight flicker (but less than when I used `setTimeout`). Note also that when there is a smaller amount of data in the table, it works correctly, so definitely a race condition.

Comment: I could probably get rid of the flicker effect but I ensuring that the view only renders once, but then I worry about data sync issues to make sure that if I have new data my view is redrawn.  Incidentally, for large data sets that can't be downloaded in the browser all at once, I'm going to be using server-side pagination, sorting, and searching, so I could always just not use DataTables for tables for which this is an issue.  Will be doing some research on data tables best practices in Ember.